# How to get `List<string>` of table names from MySQL db?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

How can I get `List<string>` of all table names contained in a MySQL database?

I want to load a complete database into a DataSet but from my understanding it seems that MySqlDataAdapter.Fill() only operates on single tables, correct? That is what I want to use the table string collection for.

EDIT:

1. I look for the correct query: The following returns 59 different items despite the database only holding 3 tables:

   ```
       MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'", connection);
       var result = command.ExecuteReader();
   ```
2. I look for C# code to parse the result of the query into a `List<string>`.

Comment: IF full db is queried at once it will be out of memory

Comment: @ArunKillu, why is that the case. It completely depends on its content. I have one database setup with several settings/properties tables that are loaded at startup of the app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Entity fraemwork, add your schema to the dbcontext then you can make something like:

```
var tableNames = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace)
                        .Select(t => t.Name)
                        .ToList();
```

EDIT:

Alternativly you can read the tablen names using a normal sql query (for example using [Show tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html)) and parse these into a list like:

```
List<String> Tablenames = new List<String>();

using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("conn_string"))
{
    string query = "show tables from YourDB";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Tablenames.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but I like to do without entity framework. But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: then you will have to use a normal sql query and parse the results into the list.

Comment: the whole point of my question was exactly how to parse the results to the list :-) (please see my second point)

Comment: great, thanks that answers my question. By the way, is there a way in .Net to ease the parsing for more complicated queries? Would linq2sql help or any other ideas?

Comment: Sure Linq is very powerfull in this, but im not really familiar with linq2sql, i can only recommend you considering to use entity framework since it provides you allready dbsets on which you can run linq queries.

Comment: thanks I will read up on the entity framework, I was just concerned how portable it is, is it always part of the project? At first glance it looks more like its part of the solution rather than project but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

- Download and install [Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) first.This is necessary to use MySQL in C# .[MySQL for Visual Studio](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/) is not necessary,but I recommend you to install it.It can help you designing MySQL databases in Visual Studio.
- Add reference to `MySql.Data`
- Add `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` in your code.

**Declare a function like this:**

```
public List<string> MySqlCollectionQuery(MySqlConnection connection, string cmd)
{
    List<string> QueryResult = new List<string>();
    MySqlCommand cmdName = new MySqlCommand(cmd, connection);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmdName.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        QueryResult.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    }
    reader.Close();
    return QueryResult;
}
```

**Then create a MySql connection and call this function:**

```
string connStr = string.Format("user={0};password={1};database={2}",
                                username,password,database);
List<string>TableNames = new List<string>();//Stores table names in List<string> form
using(MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
    Conn.Open();
    string cmdStr = "show tables";
    TableNames = MySqlCollectionQuery(Conn,cmdStr);
}
```

I did not put this in a `try ... catch` block,but it is always a good practice to do that.